# Windows File Server 2019 backup to Azure with NTFS permissions

Tags: azure, windows-server-2019, ntfs, azure-backup

We are running a windows server 2019 with File and storage services. We only use this as a file server with NTFS permissions. My backup program doesn't allow dynamic disks to be backed up and all of our file partitions are dynamic disks. So I need to find a solution to backup all of our data, delete the partitions, and recreate partitions using basic disk. Then copy the data back to the local server.

Is Azure backup the best way to do this? Will it keep all NTFS permissions intact?

Comment: Using Azure backup seems like killing a fly with a sledgehammer. Why not backup the files to an external USB drive? You can use icacls to backup and restore the permissions or you can use Robocopy to copy the files back and forth with the permissions.

Comment: It's around 20TB of data. I was just going to use Azure temp until I transfer everything back.

Comment: How long would it take to transit that much data to Azure? Any idea? Additionally, your backup solution not being able to backup dynamic disks seems... strange. Have you considered a different backup solution?

Comment: Not sure how long it would take but I'm assuming at least a few days. We are using Synology and they said that Microsoft doesn't support dynamic disks anymore so they stopped supporting it as well.